# Docker image layers vernacular – referencing layer order

Tags: docker

How do I properly convey a layer is "later" than another layer.

Consider the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
CMD python /app/app.py
```

This Dockerfile contains four commands, each of which creates a layer.

**How do I describe the RUN layer is later than the COPY layer?** Context being, later layers that install patches may mitigate vulnerabilities that are introduced in earlier layers.

### In Code

In code, the CMD layer is the bottom layer. Hence, in code, the lower a layer is, the later it is.

### [Docker overview docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/)

There is only a reference to a "final" layer.

### [About images, containers, and storage drivers | Docker Documentation,](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)

Docker references layers that supersede other layers in the following ways:

- last
- on top
- before

Docker image shows later images as "higher"

[image: Docker image shows later images as "higher"]

Comment: because of the order in the `docker history`? isn't it enough?

Comment: This is about how to verbally describe later order.